# Concatenating integer and char in C using sprintf

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, string-concatenation, printf

Within an assignment, which I program in C, I need to concatenate the symbol '#' and an integer, for instance 16, to the string "#16". This is not to be printed out, but to be passed on as an argument to another function. By my understanding, I should use the function sprintf. However, I am getting segmentation errors, so I'm obviously not doing it right.
I'll give you an example, and you can tell me what I am doing wrong:

```
void methodA(){
    char* input;
    sprintf(input, "#%d", 16);
    methodB(input);
}

void methodB(int a){
    // Code here

    // Sacrifice the power of a to Darth Sidious
}
```

EDIT: To those who answered first: char input was a typo, it was supposed to say char* input, I knew that already. Sorry about that.

Comment: You are `sprintf`ing your string into a single-character buffer for one.  Second, you are passing that `char` to `methodB` which is expecting an `int`.

Comment: You declaration `char* input;` allocates space for a pointer, not anything for it to point *at* (like an array big enough to hold at least 4 characters). Also, your `methodB()` is expecting an `int`, which is not what you're passing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sprintf` takes `char*`, not `char`.

```
int sprintf(char *str, const char *format, ...);
```

And yes, prefer using `snprintf`

Comment: And needs more space than a single character, too.  Using `snprintf()` would be better/safer.

Comment: char input was a typo, I meant as you say char* input.

Answer (score 1):

You're not initializing input so it points to undefined memory. Allocated memory first

```
void methodA(){
    char input[SIZE];  // or char* input = malloc(SIZE);
    sprintf(input, "#%d", 16);
    methodB(input);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void methodA(){
    char input[4];
    sprintf(&input[0], "#%d", 16);
    methodB(&input[0]);
}

void methodB(char *a){
    // Code here

    // Sacrifice the power of a to Darth Sidious
}
```

Note, I used the '&x[offset]' style to make it clear that we are passing the address of the first element of an array.